# How to tell if an RGB value exists in the Pantone PMS system

Tags: c#, colors

I would like a function which returns true only if the RGB value given exists in the Pantone PMS system, but it should not store all the values of the color chart itself.

Comment: You absolutely need to check against a table of values. If you don't want to maintain your own, you can perhaps query the web: http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/colorfinder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding it's not possible.
Pantone PMS is a **system**, which colors are standardized and arbitrary chosen. Color values are not determined by an algorithm, as they are in **color space**.

Therefore you **need** to have sort of lookup table for all of the values in the system.